# Good shell script to move a file to another location?

Tags: scripts, sh, mv

I'm trying to write a shell scrip to move a file to a a different location when it's found. And when it's not found to move a file from that different location to its location. This is basically my first try at writing shell scripts so be easy on me.

```
#!/bin/bash
 FILE=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libfreshwrapper.so;


if [ -f $FILE ];
then
   echo "File $FILE exists"
   echo "moving $FILE to home"
   mv -f $File /home/jon/temporary
else
   echo "File $FILE does not exists"
   echo "moving file back"
   mv -f /home/jon/temporary/libfreshwrapper.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
   echo "done!"
fi
```

this is my problem.

```
File /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libfreshwrapper.so exists
moving /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libfreshwrapper.so to home
mv: missing destination file operand after ‘/home/jon/temporary’
```

Comment: So you want to make sure both locations have the file?

Comment: I want it so that when it finds the file, it moves it to a different location when its run once. If it doesn't find it, it moves it back. I'm trying to write an enable disable plugin script

Comment: Try putting the locations in quotes?

Comment: 1. /usr/lib probably requires sudo. (./lib is root owned) 2. `mv -f $File /home/jon/temporary` is wrong. should be "$FILE"

Comment: yes i run the script with sudo

Comment: It says mv: cannot stat ‘’: No such file or directory when I put "$file" in quotes...

Comment: See my new answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the line

`mv -f $File /home/jon/temporary` (Ln 9)

to

`mv -f $FILE /home/jon/temporary`

You declared it in capitals.

Comment: What's the difference? It's the same

Comment: No, in the replacement the word `File` is in CAPS, it is `FILE`

Comment: Yup when little things go unnoticed they can create big problems. Thank you.